# What is X Y coordinate in this data set?

Tags: data

Anyone knows what the x y coordinate in this crime data set is?
https://data.cityofboston.gov/Public-Safety/Crime-Incident-Reports/7cdf-6fgx

I think it is not lat, long. How do I convert it to lat long?

Comment: If you are looking for lat/lon, why not just use the Location column a few more to the right?  The X,Y coordinates are *probably* state plane appropriate to that area, but further investigation would be needed to confirm that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The X Y coordinates are in NAD 83 Massachusetts Mainland (feetUS) EPSG:2249:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for lat/lon, why not just use the Location column a few more to the right?

According to the metadata (click the dark red About button in the upper right corner) the X,Y coordinates are state plane (appropriate to that area) in feet which have been obscured to the centroid of the reporting street segment.

Comment: Thanks. So the location column is the lat long, right? They just added that column. not even in their excel documentation file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be 3 different variables indicating the approximate location of each crime event. The X and Y seem to be a type of Easting and Northing variables respectively. I would likely guess that it is using a Massachusetts State Plane Projection system for these coordinates. Alternatively, you could use the location variable/field which has NAD 83 lat and long coordinates. If I were you, the next step is to ask about pulling information from parts of a field.

For example, in ArcGIS you would use [calculate field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004s000000) along with python code to pull information from that variable/field.